# Optimizing background image loading

Tags: javascript, css

I want to get smarter with how my background images are selected and loaded, based on how large the screen is / can get.

- Use case 1: I'm a mobile device, and only need a small background image.
- Use case 2: I'm a desktop browser, and can have any screen size

Currently, I am using a combination of pre-loading js and css to deliver a low-res background image and then swapping it for a high-res once its loaded, like so:

```
.bg {
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: grey;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('lowres.jpg');

  /* add in some media queries here to choose different lowres cropping etc */
}

.bg.highres {
  background-image: url('highres.jpg');
  /* add in some media queries here to choose different highres cropping etc */
}

#highres-loader {
  display: none;
}
```

and, in my html:

```
<div id="highres-loader">
  <img src="highres.jpg" onload="add_highres_class_to_background_image_after_it_loads()">
</div>

<div class="bg"></div>
```

This allows a low-res image to be displayed right away, while the high-res loads in the background.  And, with media queries, I can combine the above to ensure the proper bg image loads for the device.  Looks great!

However, what I find happening is: 1) I cannot prioritize the large images to necessarily load AFTER the rest of the site completes.  Ideally, it would be better to serialize it.   Also, this scheme multiplies out the number of images downloaded, which is unsatisfactory, and I think even if they aren't used.

As I was writing this question, I came upon some research here:  https://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/ that looks like I should be taking into account.  However the report is dated now, so I'm not sure what the research would reveal today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is correct but you want to make sure the high-res images start loading once the page is accessible. I've done a lot of research on this and found the below is the only way that's working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadAtOnload() {
  // Dynamically load CSS
  var ls = document.createElement("link");
  ls.rel="stylesheet";
  ls.href= "css/my-css.css";
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(ls);

  // Dynamically load Javascript/jQuery
  element = document.createElement("script");
  element.src = "js/my-js.js";
  document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("load", downloadAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", downloadAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadAtOnload;
</script>
```

Inside the my-js.js script you can load the high-res image and put it inside the correct container.

Comment: this of course makes perfect sense for solving the timing issue I'm having.  This is great, with the added benefit of the images being defined in css only.  My solution above mixes css and html for sourcing the images, which was not very DRY.  And then, with better media queries, I can prevent multiple versions of the images from downloading.

Comment: how do browsers handle the case for when the bg image changes due to a breakpoint being hit, and the image hasn't been loaded yet?  Does the background disappear or is the previous / current image retained until the new one is loaded?

Comment: I stays in place until the new one is loaded :)